# Input string 'x' is not a valid number error with JsonConvertDeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json

I have a string for billingpostalcode. When you enter pure numbers on it ex: '12345' then it is working fine. But for example you put '123aa' or 'abcde' it is producing an exception. It is a string and not an integer so i don't understand the error.

> {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: s. Path 'billingPostalCode', line 1, position 119."}

```
    string billingPostal = billingPostalCode;
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject($"{{ 'odrDetailHdr' : {orderDetailHeaderJson}, 'billingPostalCode' : {billingPostal},  'odrProductList': {orderTrackingDetailsProductJson}, 'odrDetailOtherHdr': {orderDetailOtherHeaderJson} }}");
```

Anyone has an idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is different notation between a string and a number in the json format.

```
"employee":{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York" }
```

Notice the difference between the string `"name":"John"`and the number `"age":30`, They are not interchangeable

However, in your example you could add the quotes, or use a *converter* via an *attribute* when using *json.net*